# Woher stammt die Verwendung des Infinitivs als Ersatz für den Imperativ?

Tags: infinitive, imperative

Immer häufiger sehe ich den Infinitiv, wo ich den Imperativ erwarte:

Statt

> Haltet die Einfahrt frei.

steht da also

> Einfahrt freihalten.

oder sogar

> Die Einfahrt ist freizuhalten.

[Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperativ_%28Modus%29) erwähnt den Infinitiv als mögliche Ersatzform für den Imperativ, geht aber nicht auf Grammatik und Ursprung dahinter ein.
Ich habe diese Form früher nur in der politischen Sprache und auf Schildern gesehen ("Den Klassenkampf beginnen!"), heute aber ist sie so verbreitet, dass sich sogar persönliche Nachrichten ihrer bedienen. ("Kommt ihr? Bitte hier eintragen.")

Erlaubt die Grammatik, Imperativ und Infinitiv so zu tauschen?
Wo hat dieser Tausch seinen Ursprung? Wie hat er es in die Umgangssprache geschafft?

Comment: Militärische Befehlsformen sind kurze Ansagen auf die inhaltliche Ansage beschränkt. Verstanden?!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Der Infinitiv ist eine grammatikalisch erlaubte [Ersatzform des Imperativs](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/newsletter/duden-newsletter-vom-09-12-11-1). Ich würde auch nicht von Umgangssprache reden. Dabei ist der Infinitiv nicht die einzige Ersatzform. Z. B. gibt es:

- Infinitiv ("Zimmer aufräumen!")
- Nomen ("Hilfe!")
- Partizip ("Stillgestanden!")
- Passiv ("Jetzt wird gegessen!")
- Indikativ ("Du gehst jetzt!")
- Futur ("Du wirst das Haus jetzt verlassen!")

Einen Überblick bieten die Listen von [deutschplus](http://www.deutschplus.net/pages/319) und [mein-deutschbuch](http://www.mein-deutschbuch.de/lernen.php?menu_id=32#ersatzformen).

Die Beliebtheit des Infinitivs wird seiner Kürze geschuldet sein. Befehle werden bevorzugt kurz und prägnant ausgegeben. Und "Essen fassen!" ist kürzer als "Fassen Sie essen", sofern man nicht auf die 2. Person Plural zurückgreifen möchte ("Fasst essen!").

Man muss sich keinen Kopf über Duzen oder Siezen machen und spart das Personalpronomen im Sie-Fall.

Comment: [wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperativ_(Modus)) nennt noch zwei weitere

Comment: The first two links are broken, the third is on a page with annoying ad practices.

Answer (score 4):

Der Infinitiv kann in vielen Sprachen den Imperativ ersetzen, z.B. im Spanischen. (*No fumar = nicht rauchen*.) Es erscheint mir ziemlich offensichtlich, wie es dazu kommt:

> Hier muss man die *Einfahrt freihalten.*

Oder in Sprachen, die kein passendes Äquivalent zum unpersönlichen *man* haben, vielleicht auch:

> Wer in dieser Straße parken will, muss die *Einfahrt freihalten.*

Bei Schildern (und idealerweise auch bei Dialogen in Computer-Anwendungen und Betriebssystemen) wird aber aller Ballast abgeworfen bis nur noch die Kernaussage übrigbleibt. Und das ist dann eben beispielsweise "Einfahrt freihalten", "Rasen nicht betreten", "Nichts aus dem Fenster werfen". Manchmal ist auch der Infinitiv selbst entbehrlich: "Bitte Ruhe!". Oder aus anderem Grund bleibt nur eine Nominalphrase übrig (die man nicht sinnvoll durch einen Infinitiv ergänzen könnte): "Kein Eingang".

Dasselbe Prinzip wie für Schilder gilt auch für gesprochene Befehle. Bei militärischen Kommandos gilt wohl im Prinzip auch dasselbe.

Wie John Smithers schon durch Beispiele gezeigt hat, wird durchaus auch nicht nur der Infinitiv in dieser Funktion verwendet. Einige seiner Beispiele sind ganze Sätze, die wohl für sich sprechen. Die anderen kann man zu ganzen Sätzen ergänzen, die einerseits zeigen, wo die Kurzform herkommt, und andererseits verdeutlichen, wie nützlich die Verkürzung ist:

> Du musst jetzt das *Zimmer aufräumen!*
>
> Ich benötige *Hilfe!* Ich brauche jemanden, der mir *zu Hilfe* kommt!
>
> Jetzt wird *stillgestanden!*

Der interessanteste als Imperativ gebrauchte Infinitiv, den ich bisher gesehen habe, ist auf Schildern an der Straße durch den schweizerischen Nationalpark Ofenpass zu lesen. In der Gegend wird nämlich noch Rätoromanisch gesprochen, eine romanische Sprache mit weitgehend schweizerdeutscher Phonologie und Orthographie. Wer ein bisschen Französisch kann, sollte es entziffern können:

> Non fär fö!

Auflösung:

> In französischer Schreibung: non faire feu = nein (d.h. nicht) machen Feuer.