# Warum heißt es „Jedem Kind eine Geburtstagsfeier“ und nicht „jedes Kind“?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case

Ich habe gerade diesen Titel in der Zeitung gelesen und wollte wissen, warum es nicht

> jedes Kind eine Geburtstagparty

heißt? Das Einzige, was ich mir denken konnte, ist, dass der vollständige Satz z. B.

> Organisation ABC bietet jedem Kind eine Geburtstagfeier an.

lautet, und der Redakteur ihn als Titel angepasst oder verkürzt hat – wie bei *schönen Abend*, der eigentlich *Ich wünsche dir einen schönen Abend* heißt.

Liege ich richtig oder hat das einen anderen Grund? Wäre es auch richtig, wenn man einfach sagte

> Jedes Kind eine Geburtstagsfeier

?

Comment: Du kannst richtig liegen oder recht haben, ob Du richtig bist wäre eine andere Frage ;)

Comment: @CarstenS Du hast recht. Das ist die Übersetzung von "Am I right", die natürlich nicht korrekt ist. Ich versuche immer deutsch zu denken, wenn ich Deutsch spreche und englisch, wenn ich Englisch spreche. Aber man verwechselt manchmal :)

Comment: @Infinity Ich habe deinen Beitrag ein bisschen sprachlich geglättet. Ich hoffe, du kannst von meinen Umstellungen etwas lernen. Für Fragen stehen wir dir alle gerne im [chat] zur Verfügung.

Comment: @Jan Danke schön. Ich werde bestimmt von euch lernen :)

Comment: You wouldn't say "Every child a birthday party" but "To every child a birthday party". The sense is, of course, "Every child shall have his or her party".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ohne den genauen Kontext zu kennen, nehme ich mal an, dass der Dativ hier impliziert, dass ein Verb dazugedacht werden muss wie folgt:

> Jedem Kind [gebührt] eine Geburtstagsfeier.
>
> Jedem Kind [steht] eine Geburtstagsfeier [zu].
>
> Jedem Tierchen [steht] sein Pläsierchen [zu].
>
> Jedem Tierchen [gönne man] sein Pläsierchen.

Wenn dagegen gedanklich ein Befehl zu ergänzen ist, steht der Nominativ:

> Jeder [nimmt sich gefälligst] nur ein Kreuz!

Ebenso auch, wenn man die beliebte Formulierung aus der Kaffefahrten-Werbung verkürzt:

> Jede Dame ein Teeservice aus Hartplastik, jeder Herr einen Satz Werkzeuge aus Vollgummi.

Bei der ist das bisher (glaube ich) nicht üblich, aber jeder, der die typischen Flugblätter kennt, kann das fehlende Verb ("erhält") ergänzen. Wenn eine verkürzte Form populär wird, verselbstständigt sie sich irgendwann, aber die Kasus bleiben auch dann noch dieselben, wenn niemand mehr sicher weiß, welches Verb da mal stand.

Comment: Müsste es nicht "Jeder nehme" heißen?

Comment: Nicht, wenn es bei Kreuzigungen wie beim kalten Büffet zugeht.

Comment: Das Ergebnis ist aber auch mit *nehme* dasselbe. Insofern könnte natürlich auch das die ursprüngliche Form gewesen sein.

Comment: Ich glaube, der Jussiv (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jussiv) wurde erst kürzlich im German SE erwähnt (http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25213/what-kind-of-sentence-structure-used-in-cooking-recipe)

Comment: @Philipp Zur Erklärung des Spruches: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xaI3CFhORss

Answer (score 7):

Deine Vermutung geht in die richtige Richtung.

In

> jedem Kind eine Geburtstagfeier

steht *jedes Kind* im Dativ. Der Dativ antwortet, einfach gesagt, auf "wem?"-Fragen. Das Kind wird damit als Empfänger einer Handlung dargestellt. Mangels Verb wissen wir nicht genau, welche das sein soll. Es könnte so sein, wie Du schreibst, oder etwas allgemeiner

> Jedem Kind soll eine Geburtstagsfeier zuteil werden.

Hingegen haben wir in

> jedes Kind eine Geburtstagsfeier

den Nominativ (oder Akkusativ) vorliegen. Mangels Verb (und mangels eindeutigem Kasus?) würde die Phrase wohl verstanden werden wie (*)

> Jedes Kind ist wie eine Geburtstagsfeier.

Um das zu umgehen, müsste man die Beziehung zumindest durch eine Präposition eindeutig machen:

> Eine Geburtstagsfeier *für* jedes Kind

---

(*) [Hans Adler](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/2183/hans-adler) hat in seiner Antwort zu Recht darauf hingewiesen, dass solche Konstruktionen auch als Aufforderung verstanden werden könnten. Mit passendem Kontext wäre deshalb z.B. auch eine Interpretation möglich als

> Jedes Kind [veranstalte bitte] eine Geburtstagsfeier!

Comment: «Jedes Kind *bekommt* eine Geburtstagsfeier» passt vielleicht besser als Beispiel hier?

Comment: @Dirk Du meinst im Beispiel mit der Aufforderung? Wäre auch möglich. Ich glaube, das hängt hier ganz stark vom Kontext ab (Wer nie _das Leben des Brian_ gesehen hat, kann wahrscheinlich auch mit "Jeder nur ein Kreuz" nichts anfangen, wenn es kontextlos auf einem Zettel steht). Kann ich vielleicht später noch ergänzen / ändern.

Comment: Ja, *Leben des Brian* ist eine wichtige Referenz. Und das Beispiel ist gut, weil vermutlich im englischen Sprachraum auch viele, wenngleich nicht alle, "One cross each" kennen. Vermutlich ist ebenso aus der Kantine "Jeder nur einen Pudding!" oder so etwas ähnliches sehr geläufig. Aber ich glaube, es geht nicht darum, dass ein mit **deutsch** gut befasster Leser die Verbindung herstellen kann, sondern um leicht für Fremdsprachler verständliche Beispiele. Mir gefällt die Antwort auch, weil sie die beiläufig Ersetzung "Dativ = für + Akkusativ" erklärt.