# Imperativ oder Infinitiv im User-Interface

Tags: translation, technical-terminology, imperative

Ich übersetze gerade eine User-Interface/Benutzeroberfläche und bin auf eine Frage gestoßen, die mich schon länger beschäftigt hat – ich vergesse halt immer, sie zu stellen.

Bei vielen User-Interfaces sieht man Tasten, die ihren Vorgang mit dem Infinitiv beschreiben: *Fortschritt zurücksetzen*, *Datei speichern*, *Feedback abgeben*.

Bei anderen (vor allem in Spielen, glaube ich) werden Tasten mit dem Imperativ versehen: *Setze Fortschritt zurück*, *Lade Freunde ein*, *Greife an*.

Ich bevorzuge die Formulierung mit dem Infinitiv, weiß aber eigentlich nicht, ob das eine Sache der Vorlieben ist, oder ob eine Variante „richtiger“ bzw. professioneller vorkommt als die andere. Gibt es einen Grund, die eine oder die andere zu benutzen?

Comment: sehr gute Frage. Ich persönlich sehe es wie Du als "professioneller" an, den Infinitiv zu benutzen (das andere ist so "kumpelhaft"). Habe aber auch nichts, um das zu belegen, deshalb nur der Kommentar und keine vollständige Antwort...

Comment: Deutsche UI-Gepflogenheiten sind meistens durch gedankenlose Übernahme der entsprechenden Formulierungen im Englischen entstanden. Hier ist aber der interessante Fall, dass z.B. "Save data" sowohl Infinitiv als auch Imperativ sein könnte. Dis Vorliebe für den Infinitiv muss also tatsächlich irgendwie im Deutschen begründet sein.

Comment: Ich weiß nicht, wie hier eine gute Antwort, die nicht nur eine Meinung wiedergibt aussehen sollte.

Comment: @CarstenS: Dann empfehle ich ganz einfach selbst keine Antwort zu schreiben und darauf zu warten, dass andere das wissen. Dass man etwas selbst nicht weiß bedeutet nämlich nicht, dass es niemand wissen kann.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, okay, nächstes Mal stimme ich gleich fürs Schließen anstatt dem OP Gelegenheit zu geben, etwas dazu zu schreiben, warum das nicht nur opinion based ist.

Comment: @CarstenS Ich glaube, man kann diese Frage ganz gut beantworten, ohne sich ganz und gar auf "Meinung" zu stützen. Man kann eine Frage auch beantworten, indem man für-und-wider Argumente aufzählt und die Schlußfolgerungen dem Leser überlässt.

Comment: @CarstenS Tut mir leid, ich habe deine Frage erst jetzt gesehen. Sprache ist leider grundsätzlich meinungsbestimmt – allerdings nur durch die Meinungen der überwiegenden Mehrheit. Es gibt keine Regel dagegen, ein Kochrezept mit dem Indikativ zu schreiben (*Jetzt schneidest du die Tomate in Scheiben*), das entspricht aber nicht den Normen, also der Mehrheitsmeinung. Wie dem auch sei, ich habe gehofft, dass eine Antwort existiert, die nicht nur auf Meinung basiert, sondern durch historische Beweise gemacht werden kann. (cont.)

Comment: Z.B. könnte jemand zeigen, dass der Gebrauch des Imperativs bei geschriebenen Anleitungen erst mit der Sintflut von UI-Übersetzungen aus dem Englischen anfing, welches suggerieren würde, dass dieser Gebrauch unter Einfluss des Englischen gekommen ist und daher eher abzuraten wäre. Ob das der Fall ist, weiß ich nicht, aber ich kann mir vorstellen, dass mehrere solche Argument möglich sind. Deshalb die Frage :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zunächst: Ich kenne keine normative deutschsprachige Anweisung, ob Infinitiv oder Imperativ (oder etwas anderes) zu bevorzugen wäre. "Sprachunabhängige" (sic) Ui-Guidelines verschiedener Betriebssystemhersteller (hier: Windows, teilweise auch MacOS) schreiben allerdings den Infinitiv für Aktionen ("Print") und das Gerundium (sic) für Statusmeldungen (z.B. "Printing") vor. (Englischsprachige Anwendungen müssen die Entscheidung zwischen Imperativ und Infinitiv nicht treffen: Die beiden Formen sind für alle englischen Verben gleich. Randbemerkung, eigentlich off-topic: Der Tatsache, dass viele Sprachen gar kein Gerundium kennen, scheint man in den MS Ui-Guidelines wenig Rechnung zu tragen)

Der Infinitiv als Ersatz für den Imperativ hat im Deutschen den unschätzbaren Vorteil, dass man sich keine Gedanken über die Person (zweite oder dritte) machen muss, in der Benutzer und Computer interagieren und scheint deshalb meiner Erfahrung nach für "seriöse" Anwendungen, die nicht den Eindruck erwecken sollen, zu "duzen", bevorzugt zu werden. (Anwendungen, die "Hip" sein möchten, könnten genau deswegen auch den Imperativ wählen - Die Ikea-Website ist ein gutes Beispiel dafür, die durchgängig mit Imperativ in der zweiten Person mit dem Benutzer interagiert)

Die deutsche Sprache kennt neben dem Infinitiv noch einige Ersatzformen des Imperativs, die ebenfalls zur Auswahl stünden:

1. Partizip: ("Stillgestanden!) - Als militärisch barsche Ersatzform des Imperativs wohl nur in Ausnahmefällen möglich
2. Konjunktiv: ("Würdest du bitte drucken") - Ist i.A. zu lang für Ui-Elemente und hat natürlich auch das Problem mit dem "Duzen" von oben.
3. Unpersönliches Passiv: ("Jetzt wird aber geschlafen") - Das unpersönliche Passiv ist i.A. in deutschen Benutzeroberflächen schon als Ersatzform für die englische Verlaufsform für Statusmeldungen (s.o) belegt ("es wird gedruckt") und wäre daher mißverständlich - und besonders kurz ist es auch nicht.

Darüberhinaus wären für Benutzeraktionen auch noch Substantivierungen von Verben vorstellbar (z.B. "Druck" statt "Drucken" oder "Format/Formatierung" statt "Formatieren"). Ich finde solche Formulierungen teilweise, wenn die "Aktion" nicht sofort ausgeführt wird (also nicht direkt eine Aktion ist) sondern erst weitere Benutzerinteraktion, z.B. in einer sich öffnenden Dialogbox, erfordert.

Comment: Der Sprachgebrauch von Ikea (jeder wird geduzt) hat zur Folge, dass ich dort nichts kaufe. Ich will mich nicht von wildfremden Menschen duzen lassen. Und ich kenne auch ein paar andere Leute, die aus demselben Grund eine Abneigung gegen Ikea haben. Und aus demselben Grund habe ich auch eine Abneigung gegen Computerprogramme die mich per Du ansprechen ohne mir die Möglichkeit zu geben, die Anredeform zu ändern.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich habe auch eine Einstellung dazu, aber versucht, diese Herangehensweise möglichst neutral zu formulieren. In einem Spiel z.B., mag ein "inniges Duz-Verhältnis" zwischen Computer und Benutzer ganz angebracht sein.

Comment: Kannst du die zitierten Guidelines verlinken?

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Wenn ich sie wiederfinde...

Comment: Ich würde „drucke“ als Anweisung an den Computer oder das Programm betrachten. Bei beiden finde ich „Du“ angemessen. Das heißt ja nicht, dass der Computer mich auch duzen muss.
Gibt es Programmiersprachen, bei denen Befehle(!) ins Deutsche übersetzt wurden? Wie wird es da gehalten? Schon bei dem berühmten „GO TO“ ist ja nicht klar, ob das ein Infinitiv oder Imperativ ist, auch wenn ich es damals als Imperativ aufgefasst habe.

Comment: Bei z.B. "Printing" in einer Statusmeldung handelt es sich nicht um das Gerundium, sondern um das gleich aussehende Partizip Präsens. Das Gerundium ist ein Nomen, und das macht bei einer Statusmeldung keinen Sinn. Analog könnte man im Deutschen also "Druckend" verwenden, was aber seltsam wirken würde, vermutlich weil das Deutsche im Gegensatz zum Englischen keine Verlaufsform keinnt, die das Partizip Präsens verwendet.

Comment: @rha Was du sagst, stimmt für Latein. Im Englischen wird ohne weiter draufzuschauen, grob alles, was mit -ing aufhört, als "gerund" bezeichnet.

Comment: @tofro Das Englische unterscheidet sehr wohl zwischen *gerund* und *present participle*, s. z. B. die engtlischsprachigen Wikipedia-Seiten zu den Begriffen *Gerund* und *Participle*.

Comment: @RHa Dann lies mal den ersten Satz, der da steht (im **gerund**-Artikel): *Traditional grammar makes a distinction within -ing forms between present participles and gerunds, a distinction that is not observed in such modern grammars as A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language and The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language.* - Mit der eigentlichen Frage hat das aber nicht mehr viel zu tun.

Answer (score 3):

Es gibt hinreichend viele Beispiele für den Infinitiv aus vergleichsweise grauer Vorzeit:

- *hier öffnen* auf Konserven und ähnlichen Gefäßen
- *drücken* und *ziehen* auf Türen
- *Während der Fahrt nicht mit dem Fahrer sprechen*

Damit ist klar: Der Infinitiv ist (zumindest: auch) richtig. Er hat zudem den Charme, dass er bezüglich Sender und Empfänger neutral ist. Dagegen hat der Imperativ das Problem, dass er auf das Programm zielt (das die Anweisung ausführt), aber nur der Benutzer den Text liest.

Da in den Antworten zu [dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/4874/1696) der Infinitiv plausibel als Ersatzform für den Imperativ dargestellt wird, scheint der Unterschied ohnehin nur gradueller Natur zu sein.

Comment: Ich finde, die Auswahl für "Du" oder "Sie", die man im Deutschen beim Imperativ treffen muss und vor der man sich mit dem Infinitiv drücken kann, macht schon einen entscheidenden Unterschied (zum Nachteil des Imperativs) aus.

Answer (score 2):

Vergleichen wir mal Deutsch und Englisch:

- Infinitiv

  > En.: to save, to invite friends, to attack
  > De.: speichern, Freunde einladen, angreifen
- Imperativ

  > En.: save, invite friends, attack
  > De. du: speichere, lade Freunde ein, greif an
  > De. Sie: speichern Sie, laden Sie Freunde ein, greifen Sie an

Auf Englisch ist der Imperativ immer um 3 Zeichen kürzer als der Infinitiv, weil er ohne das Wörtchen *"to"* (und das darauf folgende Leerzeichen) auskommt. Im Deutschen ist es umgekehrt. Da ist meist der Infinitiv die kürzere Form. Und genau diese Länge ist entscheidend, denn auf Schaltflächen hat man nur wenig Platz. Davon kann jeder ein Lied singen, der schon mal versucht hat ein englisches Interface ins Deutsche zu übersetzen, wenn die Designer, die nur Englisch sprechen und keine Ahnung von Fremdsprachen haben, keine Möglichkeit vorgesehen haben, die Schaltflächen größer oder die Schrift kleiner zu machen.

Daher wird auf Schaltflächen in den meisten Fällen auf Englisch der Imperativ und auf Deutsch die infinite Form verwendet. Auf Englisch gibt der Anwender also einen Befehl an das Programm, auf Deutsch wählt der Anwender eine von mehreren Optionen aus.

Außerdem hat der deutsche Imperativ auch noch das Problem, dass zwischen den beiden Höflichkeitsformen unterschieden werden muss, und das kann man sehr elegant umgehen indem man den Infinitiv verwendet.

Comment: Englischen Oberflächen zu unterstellen, den Imperativ vor dem Infinitiv zu bevorzugen, ist ein bißchen leichtsinnig: Die beiden Formen sehen für alle englischen Verben gleich aus.

Comment: @tofro: Ich glaube im Text den Unterschied zwischen Infinitiv (mit *"to"*) und Imperativ (ohne "*to"*) ausreichend dargestellt zu haben.

Comment: Ich habe das genau deshalb geschrieben, weil z.B. die Windows UI-Guidelines sinngemäß  sagen: "Verwenden Sie *Infinitive* (z.B. "Print") für Befehle".

Comment: Es stimmt nicht, dass der Infinitiv immer mit *to* steht. Der einfache Infinitiv steht z.B. mit Modalverben: *You must **leave***, you *can **quit***.

Comment: @DavidVogt Den ohne "to" nennt der Engländer auch "zero infinitive". Ich halte mich da aber raus - Mir reicht es für diesen Kontext schon, wenn die Windows-UI-Guidelines *meinen*, "Print" oder "Save" seien Infinitiv-Formen.