# Wie ist es richtig, wenn man es kürzer sagen will?

Tags: meaning

"Wenn es richtig ist, gib zu, wenn es falsch ist, widersprich!" (Brauche ich ein es hier?) Kann ich in einer kurzen Version sagen: "Wenn richtig, zugeben, wenn falsch, widersprechen"?

Comment: Bist du dir sicher, dass [zugeben](https://www.dict.cc/?s=zugeben) das richtige Wort ist? Meinst du vielleicht [zustimmen](https://www.dict.cc/?s=zustimmen)?

Comment: Related [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/70063/1696).

Answer (score 4):

Das kann man tatsächlich so sagen: Der Infinitiv kann im Deutschen als Ersatz für den Imperativ dienen. Das geschieht regelmäßig u.a. auf Beschilderungen (z.B. im Bus: "Hinten aussteigen").

Comment: Manchmal allerdings, weil "hinten" als unfein empfunden wird, auch unfreiwillig komisch: "*rückwärts aussteigen*".

Comment: @bakunin Wo genau wird denn "hinten" als "unfein" empfunden? Bei uns steht das in jedem Bus.

Comment: ich kann mich noch an eine Zeit erinnern, in der Straßenbahnen Schaffner hatten. Die sagten regelmäßig "Bitte rückwärts aussteigen/einsteigen."

Comment: @bakunin ...und alle kommen mit dem Ar*** zuerst aus dem Bus... Denn *rückwärts* und *hinten* ist nicht dasselbe.

Comment: Ja, genau - deswegen ja auch *unfreiwillig komisch*

Answer (score 3):

Tofro hat die Frage schon beantwortet, nur zur Ergänzung:

> "Wenn es richtig ist, gib zu, wenn es falsch ist, widersprich!" (Brauche ich ein es hier?)

Ja, da wird noch ein "es" mehr gebraucht:

> "Wenn es wahr ist, gib **es** zu, wenn es falsch ist, widersprich!"

Comment: Vielen Dank  aber wieso kein „es“ nach „wiedersprechen“

Comment: Einen Grund kann ich da leider nicht nennen. "Etwas zugeben" braucht immer sein  Akkusativobjekt, "widersprechen" braucht kein Objekt.